# submitting form data to mysql one question at a time

Tags: php, mysql, survey

I have a simple survey here: access.mwjt.co.uk/feedback where have only 1 question displayed at once - I'd like to submit answers to mysql individually and then post a time stamp to mark survey complete on the final one. These are tracked with a unique ID.

I've used a href link and GET to cycle the questions, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to submit the form without writing ALL the data (survey ID, question ID, user ID, question type, answer, comment) into the URL (i.e. ?s=blah&q=blah etc)

Please can someone enlighten me on how to submit survey data using a text link (javascript?)

Comment: Im confused - are you asking how to write to mysql or how to page throught the questions and maintain some sort of state?

Comment: Apologies link is http://access.mwjt.co.uk/feedback/index.php?s=test

Comment: @ethrbunny - sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm looking for a method to write to mysql without putting all the data in the URL and using GET. Thanks!

Comment: @watcher has the notion. Store the (growing)collection of responses in a session variable. Commit them all at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting a unique ID for the survey and submitting the results for each question using GET - makes the URL long, but works fine!

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not want to be storing the responses in the URL, but rather in PHP Sessions, but you still have options.

(1) You can keep track of the responses in SESSION, and then write the entire record upon completion.

**OR**

(2) If the response columns in your survey table can accept nulls, you can insert the record with NULLs for the responses at the beginning of the survey and then just update the record once each question is asked.

Downside with 1: If someone begins the survey and then leaves before completed, you have not collected any data.

Downside with 2: If someone begins the survey and then leaves before completed, you have NULL values in your table, but at least you collected something.